# Can not forward docker container port to host

Tags: port-forwarding, docker, ports

I am trying to forward docker container to host machine. I am using following command

```
docker run -d -p 80:8000 nginx
```

I have tried very hard, but not able to access nginx from `http://localhost:8000` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

I can access nginx from container's IP `http://172.17.0.2`

I have tried different images have made one from `Dockerfile` but port forwarding is not working for any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publish port flag aka `-p` syntax is `host port:container port`. In other words, when you do the `docker run`, docker is binding port 8000 of your container to port 80 of your host. So the URL to access is just `http://localhost` since browser will connect to port 80 by default for the http protocol.

The fact that just `http://172.17.0.2` works is because you're accessing the port 80, not 8000.